# How can I display all the calendar dates in jsp, for a selected year in years dropdown and selected month in months dropdown?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am having two dropdowns one is year drop-down which displays current year and 2 more years from the current year. and I am having months dropdown which displays all 12 months. I want to display all calendar dates from 1st to 31st in horizontal for the user selected month in months dropdown and for the selected year in years dropdown in next jsp after clicking submit in selection page. Language used Java

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript?  I feel Java would be an odd choice for this.

Comment: Could you show us some piece of your work on which the community could help you. Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: I suggest that you use `jquery.ui.datepicker`

Answer (score 0):

Like [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) suggets you should give a try to a CSS framework which has a built-in calendar component.

Here is a list of some of them :

- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)
- [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)
- [Bulma](https://bulma.io/)
- [Metro UI](https://metroui.org.ua/datepicker.html)